# Send user id and post id with comment

Tags: php, laravel

I am following a laravel tutorial and created a form to create a comment on a post with the user_id. I can't seem to understand how I pass the user_id.

`Post` Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [];

  public function comments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
  }

  public function addComment($body)
  {
    $this->comments()->create(compact('body'));
  }

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

`Comment`Model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function post()
    {
      $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
      $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`User` Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function posts()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function publish(Post $post)
    {
      $this->posts()->save($post);
    }

}
```

`CommentsController.php`

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Post $post)
    {
      $this->validate(request(), ['body' => 'required|min:2']);

      $post->addComment(request('body'));

      return back();
    }
}
```

As you can see I call `->addComment` in the `Post` Model to add the comment. It worked fine untill I added user_id to the `Comments` table. What is the best way to store the user id? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `addComment` method :

```
public function addComment($body)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $this->comments()->create(compact('body', 'user_id'));
}
```

PS : Assuming that the user is authenticated.

**UPDATE**

```
public function addComment($body)
{
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->fill(compact('body'));
    $this->comments()->save($comment);
}
```

Create a new instance of the comment without savingit and you only need to save a comment in the post because a post already belongs to a user

Comment: It works. But isnt there a better way to do this? For example I submit my post with the `publish function` in the `user` model. It takes the user_id automatically.

Comment: I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comments()

Comment: @JustinTime Sorry what about now :)

Comment: Now I get the same error as before..:(  Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @JustinTime use the last update i think it will solve the problem ;)

Comment: I don't think it works. What should `$post` be? I tried every variable with no succes :p

Comment: It this :p sorry my mistake

Comment: Yes, I thought so. But no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to handle ids manually, let eloquent handle it for you:

```
$user = Auth::user(); // or $request->user()
$user->comments()->save(new Comment());
```

[more information about saving eloquent models.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Comment: If I do it this way it starts asking for post_id. How let I handle eloquent both?

Comment: `new Comment()` is just an example placeholder. The comment object should be created beforehand, you can use the same structure to save a comment to a post.